# Using HashMap to count the quantity of certain integers from an array

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have an array that looks like this: values consisting of 14 integers

```java
String[] helloarray = new String[]
{"30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","60","61","62","63"};
```

Using an hashmap as below:

```java
Map<String, Integer> hellocnt  = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

The goal is to find the occurrence or find the total quantity of each of these integers that exist in the file?

```java
// using bufferedreader to read and extract the lines
// and integers from the file and storing it in intvalue
String temp[] = line.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    String intvalue = temp[i];
}
```

Now I need to match how many times/quantity of each integer exists in the file (intvalue)

```java
int e = 0;
for (e = 0; e < helloarray.length; e++) {
    if (intvalue.contains(helloarray[e])) {
        System.out.println("found: " + helloarray[e]);
        if (helloarray[e] == "32") {
            // Should I use the hashmap here since I don't want to use
            // MULTIPLE IF BLOCKS checking for each integers and want 
            // to reuse the same map function and store the incremented 
            // counter after the completion?
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest an optimized less brute force method to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is as follows.

1. After setting up the array and map like so:

```java
String[] helloarray = new String[]
        {"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "60", "61", "62", "63"};
Map<String, Integer> hellocnt = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String str : helloarray)
    hellocnt.put(str, 0);
```

2. For each line that you read:

```java
String temp[] = line.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    String intvalue = temp[i];
    if (hellocnt.containsKey(intvalue)) {
        hellocnt.put(intvalue, hellocnt.getOrDefault(intvalue, 0) + 1);
    }
}
```

3. You can then view the contents of the map simply by doing:

```java
System.out.println(hellocnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in the input file, you have numbers separated by space, e.g.

```
34 45 345 345 345 546523 423 234 23 4234 234 23412
234 345 435 456 453 643 455324 45523 657 87686 565
9393 8584 343 4324
```

The following code can be used to get count of the numbers in the given file.

```
public Map<String, Integer> getNumbersCount(String fileName) throws IOException{
    Map<String, Integer> numberVsCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
    String line;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
        String numbers[] = line.split(" ");
        for(String number : numbers) {
            int count = numberVsCountMap.getOrDefault(number, 0);
            numberVsCountMap.put(number, count + 1);
        }
    }
    return numberVsCountMap;
}
```

Edited Code(with filtering)

```
    public Map<String, Integer> getNumbersCount(String fileName, String [] filterArray) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Integer> numberVsCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> filterSet = Arrays.stream(filterArray).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
    String line;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
        String numbers[] = line.split(" ");
        for(String number : numbers) {
            if(filterSet.contains(number)) {
                int count = numberVsCountMap.getOrDefault(number, 0);
                numberVsCountMap.put(number, count + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return numberVsCountMap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response,it looks more efficient and more optimized but i just wanted to find out the list of numbers from my original array (helloarray) that matches with the values within the file and get only the count of those numbers,not for all the numbers that exist in the file.

Comment: @sarah you can use the above map and then filter it for the numbers that are there in the file.

Comment: Anyway, I just edited the code to include filtering based on the filterArray, i.e. helloArray as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 8* you can use [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```java
String[] arr = {"37", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "36", "37", "37"};
// HashMap can be used as well
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
// if the value is absent then 1, otherwise increase and update it
for (String str : arr) map.merge(str, 1, Integer::sum);
// output
System.out.println(map);
// {31=1, 32=1, 33=1, 34=1, 35=1, 36=2, 37=3}
```